# Score function for a flashcard game in python

Tags: python

I am trying to add a very simple score function to an also very simple flashcard game and I can't make the game remember the value of the variable containing the score (it always resets it 0). The score is obviously relying on the honesty of the user (and that's fine) that has to press "Y" when guessing the word.

```
    from random import *

def add_score():
    pos_score = 0
    score = input("Press Y if you got the correct word or N if you got it wrong!" )
    if score == 'Y':
        pos_score += 1
    print(pos_score)

def show_flashcard():
    """ Show the user a random key and ask them
        to define it. Show the definition
        when the user presses return.    
    """
    random_key = choice(list(glossary))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary[random_key])

def add_flashcard():
    """ This function allows the user to add a new
        word and related value to the glossary. It will
        be activated when pressing the "a" button.
    """    
    key = input("Enter the new word: ")
    value = input("Enter the definition: ")

    glossary[key] = value
    print("New entry added to glossary.")




# Set up the glossary

glossary = {'word1':'definition1',
            'word2':'definition2',
            'word3':'definition3'}

# The interactive loop

exit = False
while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard, a to add a new card. or q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        exit = True
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_flashcard()
        add_score()
    elif user_input == 'a':
        add_flashcard()
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q, a or s.')
```

Some notes: 
I am aware that right now only the positive score is implemented in the code, but I figured it would be better to proceed step by step and have that working first.

Comment: Just a side note, but it might be easier to get rid of the line with `exit = False` and say `while True:` and then `if user_input == 'q':` you can `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

In your `def add_score()`, you initialise the variable to `0` every time. Also, it is a local variable, which means you can only reference it from within your function `add_score()`. This means that every time you exit that function, that variable is completely deleted.

## Solution

You need to make that a global variable, that is, initialise it to 0 at the start of the game, and outside your function. Then inside your `add_score` you simply reference to the global variable and increase it without initialising it every time:

```
from random import *

def add_score():
    score = input("Press Y if you got the correct word or N if you got it wrong!" )
    if score == 'Y':
        global pos_score
        pos_score += 1
    print(pos_score)

# Set up the glossary

glossary = {'word1':'definition1',
            'word2':'definition2',
            'word3':'definition3'}

# The interactive loop
pos_score = 0 #NOTE you initialise it here as a global variable
exit = False
while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard, a to add a new card. or q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        exit = True
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_flashcard()
        add_score()
    elif user_input == 'a':
        add_flashcard()
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q, a or s.')
```

Note I skipped the irrelevant functions. However, usually changing the scope of variables like this is considered bad practice. What you should do is either have a class -- a bit overly complicated for this example -- or return a value to add from your `add_score` and add that value in the main loop. This would be the code:

```
from random import *

def add_score():
    score = input("Press Y if you got the correct word or N if you got it wrong!" )
    if score == 'Y':
        #global pos_score
        #pos_score += 1
        #print(pos_score)
        return 1
    return 0

def show_flashcard():
    """ Show the user a random key and ask them
        to define it. Show the definition
        when the user presses return.    
    """
    random_key = choice(list(glossary))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary[random_key])

def add_flashcard():
    """ This function allows the user to add a new
        word and related value to the glossary. It will
        be activated when pressing the "a" button.
    """    
    key = input("Enter the new word: ")
    value = input("Enter the definition: ")

    glossary[key] = value
    print("New entry added to glossary.")

# Set up the glossary

glossary = {'word1':'definition1',
            'word2':'definition2',
            'word3':'definition3'}

# The interactive loop
pos_score = 0 #NOTE you initialise it here as a global variable
exit = False
while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter s to show a flashcard, a to add a new card. or q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        exit = True
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_flashcard()
        pos_score += add_score()
        print(pos_score)
    elif user_input == 'a':
        add_flashcard()
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q, a or s.')
```